# How can i remove the Tick button in Coding4Fun MessagePrompt

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried to hide the default check button inside message prompt.but i could not find any property to hide.have only IsCancelVisible button property.Now i want to create custom Ok button instead of default check button.Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code working fine.

```
 // remove all buttons
    messagePrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Clear();
```

For example, if you want your own button to be displayed below, use the following code:

```
var messagePrompt = new MessagePrompt
{
    Title = "Simple Message",
    Message = "This is a demo of the Coding4Fun MessagePrompt."
};

// remove all buttons
messagePrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Clear();

// add your own
Button button;
messagePrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(button = new Button()
    {
        Content = "Close"
    });

// handle click state
button.Click += button_Click;
```

enjoy this code ....

Comment: Thank you so much Prabhakar.keep in touch.good work